# C++ serial thread executor

Tags: android, c++, multithreading, c++11, java-native-interface

Coming from a Java environment (specifically Android) I've never had any problems with executing some code in a new thread without blocking the main thread.
As I have to work with C++ now I have stumbled upon the follwing issue.

A client code executes my native (C++) code through JNI:

```
JNIEXPORT jbyteArray JNICALL
Java_com_native_project_NativeInterface_processData(JNIEnv *env, jobject instance, jbyteArray inputData_) {
    vector<unsigned char> inputData = jbyteArrayToBytes(env, inputData_);
    const vector<unsigned char> &result = getDataProcessor(env, instance).processData(inputData);
    return bytesTojbyteArray(env, result);
}

DataProcessor getDataProcessor(JNIEnv *env, jobject instance) {
    return DataProcessor(env, instance);
}
```

Then in my `DataProcessor` I want to do two thigs:

- process the data and return it ASAP
- write the data to activity log (eg. database) without delaying the response (so first return the response and then log the data)

Example code:

```
class BasicAsync {
private:
    void logToDB(const vector<unsigned char> &inputData) {
        // connect to DB and write data to it
    }

    vector<unsigned char> compute(const vector<unsigned char> &inputData) {
        vector<unsigned char> result = vector<unsigned char>();
        // rocket-science computation in here
        return result;
    }

public:
    vector<unsigned char> processData(const vector<unsigned char> &inputData) {
        // perform data computation and produce output
        vector<unsigned char> result = compute(inputData);

        // create a thread that writes the data to activity log without delaying the response return
        logToDB(inputData);

        //return result while data is written to activity log
        return result;
    }
}
```

My main concers are:

1. Is it possible in C++ (I'm using C++ 11)?
2. If it takes a while to write the data to database what happens to the `DataProcessor` object during that time (as it should be destroyed after returning response via JNI as its lifetime scope ends - maybe I'm missing something here)?
3. Is there any serial thread executor so that I could write a few things to the database (they would be put into a FIFO queue and persisted in sequence in the same thread)?

Comment: I've no idea about jni, but you can create a thread that writes into the database and immediately detach it.

Comment: However, be aware that creating a thread is a costly operation, so having a single dedicated thread for logging, as you suggested would certainly be more efficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Yes
2. Consider a variant of the [Active Object Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_object) to implement a serial execution queue to do your long-running work that must be serialised:

```c++
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <functional>
#include <queue>

class SerialExecutionQueue
{
public:
    typedef std::function<void()>   QueueItem;

    SerialExecutionQueue() :
    m_shouldQuit(false),
    m_executor([this]()
       {
           executor();
       })
    {

    }

    void enqueueWork(QueueItem item)
    {
        {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> l(m_mutex);
            m_queue.push(item);
        }
        m_cv.notify_all();
    }

    void executor()
    {
        while (!m_shouldQuit)
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m_mutex);
            while (m_queue.size())
            {
                auto item = m_queue.front();
                m_queue.pop();
                m_mutex.unlock();
                item();
                m_mutex.lock();
            }
            m_cv.wait(lock);
        }
    }

private:
    bool                    m_shouldQuit;
    std::condition_variable m_cv;
    std::mutex              m_mutex;
    std::queue<QueueItem>   m_queue;
    std::thread             m_executor;
};
```

```c++
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    SerialExecutionQueue queue;

    queue.enqueueWork([]()
          {
              std::cout << "Did some work 1" <<std::endl;
          });


    queue.enqueueWork([]()
          {
              std::cout << "Did some work 2" <<std::endl;
          });

    sleep(1);

    queue.enqueueWork([]()
          {
              std::cout << "Did some work 3" <<std::endl;
          });

    sleep(10);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```js
Did some work 1
Did some work 2
Did some work 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Prior to 2011, one had to use native APIs like pthreads directly or deploy third party wrapper libs, like those from boost, but since 2011, C++ offers a quite fat standardized [thread](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread) interface.

Maybe you first have a look at that yourself, try it, and add more specific questions to your post; I will then extend this answer accordingly.